# Change jupyter notebook theme to highlight R functions

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, syntax-highlighting, jupyter-lab

I'm using the R programming language with jupyter notebook, but functions are not highlighted like for Python. Is there a way to modify the default theme?

Just to be clear, below I posted 2 images to show the difference between jupyter notebook and RStudio:

[image]

[image]

as you can see, functions like length, sort etc. are painted with their own color.

Comment: I don't think that a new theme would be enough as those are annotated as `cm-variable` in the default [R mode](https://codemirror.net/mode/r/) tokenizer in CodeMirror (which is the editor used by Jupyter Notebook and JupyterLab). You could create a custom improved R mode for CodeMirror labelling those as `cm-builtin` by extending the existing mode.